# Checkbox doesn't change when clicked in dropdownbutton

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `DropdownButton` and I am facing the following issue. I'm using a checkbox in elements, but when I click on an element, I don't get a checkmark indicating that the `checkbox` has been clicked. As a result, I need to close and reopen it, and then I will see the changes that were clicked on the "`checkbox`". The second problem is that when I select one element, all elements are selected for me. As a final result, I need to get so that I can select an element and the `checkbox` is immediately marked, if 2 elements are needed, then two, and so on. Tell me how to fix these problems, I will be grateful for the help?

**dropdown**

```
class DropdownWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> items;
  SvgPicture? icon;
  double width;

  DropdownWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
    required this.icon,
    required this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropdownWidget> createState() => _DropdownWidgetState();
}

class _DropdownWidgetState extends State<DropdownWidget> {
  String? selectedValue;
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.items.isNotEmpty) {
      selectedValue = widget.items[1];
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.width,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          items: widget.items
              .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            if (item == selectedValue)
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 0,
                              ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                item,
                                style: constants.Styles.smallTextStyleWhite,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Checkbox(
                              checkColor: Colors.black,
                              value: isChecked,
                              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  isChecked = value!;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
          value: selectedValue,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = value as String;
            });
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.arrowDropdown),
          iconSize: 21,
          buttonHeight: 27,
          itemHeight: 47,
          dropdownMaxHeight: 191,
          dropdownWidth: 140,
          dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            border: Border.all(
              color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
            ),
            color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
          ),
          selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
            return widget.items.map(
              (item) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    widget.icon ?? const SizedBox(),
                    const SizedBox(width: 8),
                    Text(
                      item,
                      style: constants.Styles.bigBookTextStyleWhite,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ).toList();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**items**

```
final List<String> items = const [
    "All EV's",
    'Main EV',
    '<EV2>',
  ];
```

Comment: For second issue, You've made isChecked variable in parent class. When you change it's value it well rebuild the UI and in the code it well set the value for all the items in the list not on specific one

Comment: And how to make the value of the checkbox change immediately when clicked and not have to close / open the list?

Comment: I will make you example to describe how to implement it

Comment: I would be grateful if you can make an example where the checkbox works correctly, the pressed element is immediately displayed and immediately removed if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this example explains the concept. For simplcity I made simple a new file, run it and see the results:

Then main idea in two lists, `_checkList` contain values of the `CheckBox` and `_selectedList` handles the main dropdown widget to show the selection.

Feel free to ask any questions and I'm happy to help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AnimationDemo(number: 5);
  }
}

class AnimationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimationDemo({Key? key, this.number = 2}) : super(key: key);
  final int number;

  @override
  State<AnimationDemo> createState() => _AnimationDemoState();
}

class _AnimationDemoState extends State<AnimationDemo> {
  late List<bool> _checkList;
  late List<int> _selectedIndex;

  bool _isOpen = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _checkList = List.filled(widget.number, false);
    _selectedIndex = <int>[];
    super.initState();
  }

  List<DropDownItem> generateItems() {
    var tmp = <DropDownItem>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < _checkList.length; i++) {
      tmp.add(DropDownItem(
        isChecked: _checkList[i],
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _checkList[i] = value!;
            if (value && !_selectedIndex.contains(i)) {
              _selectedIndex.add(i);
            } else {
              _selectedIndex.remove(i);
            }
          });
        },
      ));
    }

    return tmp;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text((_selectedIndex.isEmpty)
                    ? 'Nothing Selected'
                    : _selectedIndex.join(',')),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isOpen = !_isOpen;
                  });
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          AnimatedOpacity(
            opacity: (_isOpen) ? 1 : 0,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: generateItems(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropDownItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isChecked;
  final Function(bool?)? onChanged;

  const DropDownItem({Key? key, this.onChanged, this.isChecked = false})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        const Expanded(child: Text('Demo item')),
        Checkbox(value: isChecked, onChanged: onChanged)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Tell me, could you show me in an example with my code? It's just that in your code, as I understand it, the opening list shifts all elements down, but I need the list to open above the widgets.

Comment: I need your full widget code because there is missing part in your code

Comment: try my code to understand the concept. create new file paste the code. and in main() put the TestPage class to experiment

Comment: Yes, I tried your code. But I just don’t fully understand how to add it to my code so that checkboxes are worked out.
And I added the entire code of the widget, only the colors, the icon and fonts need to be replaced with my own, and so all the code is provided.

Comment: I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2

Comment: I will give it a shot when i head home early

Comment: ok, i'll be grateful if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to achieve the Multiselect dropdown with DropdownButton2:

```
final List<String> items = [
  'Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
];
List<String> selectedItems = [];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: Align(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            child: Text(
              'Select Items',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          items: items.map((item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: item,
              //disable default onTap to avoid closing menu when selecting an item
              enabled: false,
              child: StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (context, menuSetState) {
                  final _isSelected = selectedItems.contains(item);
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      _isSelected
                              ? selectedItems.remove(item)
                              : selectedItems.add(item);
                      //This rebuilds the StatefulWidget to update the button's text
                      setState(() {});
                      //This rebuilds the dropdownMenu Widget to update the check mark
                      menuSetState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          _isSelected
                                  ? const Icon(Icons.check_box_outlined)
                                  : const Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                          const SizedBox(width: 16),
                          Text(
                            item,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          //Use last selected item as the current value so if we've limited menu height, it scroll to last item.
          value: selectedItems.isEmpty ? null : selectedItems.last,
          onChanged: (value) {},
          buttonHeight: 40,
          buttonWidth: 140,
          itemHeight: 40,
          itemPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
            return items.map(
                      (item) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    selectedItems.join(', '),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ).toList();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Also, I've added it as an example to the package doc "Example 4" so you can get back to it later.

Comment: I'll test it and let you know if it works or not

Comment: There is one difficulty that it will not work to style the button checkbox in the style I need, so that the borders are gray and the checkmark is purple