# How to select all checkboxes in dropdownbutton flutter when selecting one checkbox?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a drop down list with checkbox elements. Tell me, can I make it so that when selecting 1 element, in my case it is `All EV's`, all other checkboxes of the elements in the drop-down list are selected and if you click again, they disappear? I still don’t understand how to implement this and whether it’s real, I’ll be grateful if you help, maybe I’m trying in vain and this function cannot be implemented with dropdown.

**list**

```
final List<String> carList = const [
    "All EV's",
    'Main EV',
    '<EV2>',
  ];
```

**dopdown**

```
class CheckboxDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  final SvgPicture? icon;
  final double width;

  const CheckboxDropdown({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
    this.icon,
    required this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckboxDropdown> createState() => _CheckboxDropdown();
}

class _CheckboxDropdown extends State<CheckboxDropdown> {
  String? selectedValue;
  bool selected = false;

  final List _selectedTitles = [];
  final List _selectedTitlesIndex = [];

  final GFCheckboxType type = GFCheckboxType.basic;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.items.isNotEmpty) {
      _selectedTitles.add(widget.items[1]);
    }
  }

  void _onItemSelect(bool selected, int index) {
    if (selected == true) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTitles.add(widget.items[index]);
        _selectedTitlesIndex.add(index);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTitles.remove(widget.items[index]);
        _selectedTitlesIndex.remove(index);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.width,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          offset: const Offset(0, -12),
          items: List.generate(
            widget.items.length,
            (index) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: widget.items[index],
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (context, setStateSB) => GFCheckboxListTile(
                    value: _selectedTitles.contains(widget.items[index]),
                    onChanged: (bool selected) {
                      _onItemSelect(selected, index);
                      setStateSB(() {});
                    },
                    selected: selected,
                    title: Text(
                      widget.items[index],
                      style: constants.Styles.smallTextStyleWhite,
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 13),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0, left: 0),
                    size: 22,
                    activeBgColor: constants.Colors.greyCheckbox,
                    activeBorderColor: constants.Colors.greyXMiddle,
                    inactiveBgColor: constants.Colors.greyCheckbox,
                    activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.checkboxIcon),
                    inactiveBorderColor: constants.Colors.greyXMiddle,
                    type: type,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          hint: Row(
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.carDropdown),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
              _selectedTitles.length > 1
                  ? const Text('Selected EV',
                      style: constants.Styles.xSmallHeavyTimerTextStyleWhite)
                  : Text(_selectedTitles.join().toString(),
                      style: constants.Styles.bigBookTextStyleWhite),
              if (_selectedTitles.isEmpty)
                const Text('Select EV',
                    style: constants.Styles.xSmallHeavyTimerTextStyleWhite)
            ],
          ),
          value: selectedValue,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = value as String;
            });
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.arrowDropdown),
          iconSize: 21,
          buttonHeight: 27,
          itemHeight: 47,
          dropdownMaxHeight: 185,
          dropdownWidth: 140,
          dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              border: Border.all(
                color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
              ),
              color: constants.Colors.greyDark),
          selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
            return widget.items.map(
              (item) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    widget.icon ?? const SizedBox(),
                    const SizedBox(width: 8),
                    Text(
                      item,
                      style: constants.Styles.bigBookTextStyleWhite,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ).toList();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `_onItemSelect` function to something like this:

```
void _onItemSelect(bool selected, int index) {
    if (selected == true) {
      setState(() {
       
        //Check if its "All EV's" index
        if (index == 0) {
          _selectedTitles = List.from(widget.items);
          _selectedTitlesIndex = List.generate(widget.items.length, (index) => index);
        } else{
          _selectedTitles.add(widget.items[index]);
          _selectedTitlesIndex.add(index);
        }
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        if (index == 0) {
          _selectedTitles.clear();
          _selectedTitlesIndex.clear();
        } else{
          _selectedTitles.remove(widget.items[index]);
          _selectedTitlesIndex.remove(index);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I'll try and let you know the result

Comment: Is that what you did with my code?

Comment: I've updated on your code

Comment: Tell me, I don’t have selectedItems in my code, what should I use instead of this variable?

Comment: I tried your code, but I ran into a problem that the checkmark in the selected elements is not displayed when I click on the All EV's button

Comment: I understand, I'm sorry. Yes, the checkboxes are displayed, but only when I close and reopen the dropdownbutton. And selectedItems is just a new list in which the value is written, I also added it to myself.
Tell me, is it possible to make it so that all the checkboxes in all elements are immediately displayed and not have to be closed and opened to see the changes?

Comment: And tell me why the selectedItems list was created if I don’t use it anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, That line shouldn't be there. I've edited it.

Comment: Yes, you can do that using StatefulBuilder. Refer to my answer on your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72142344/checkbox-doesnt-change-when-clicked-in-dropdownbutton/72246313#72246313

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for your help, I'll try it.
Such a question, do you know where you can learn Flutter more, maybe practice with logical tasks?

Comment: Tell me in more detail, is it possible to do if I clicked on All EV's - all elements were selected and if I click on one selected element (except All EV's) uncheck it, then the check mark in All EV's is automatically unchecked too?

Comment: I think practice more on projects is the best way. Also, Advanced courses could be helpful.

Comment: At start of your "else" check if "All EV's" is selected then clear _selectedTitles list. There might be better solution but this should work.

Comment: And could you show how to do it, because for some reason it doesn’t work for me (

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable selected to list boolean
add some code to onChanged in GFCheckboxListTile,

```
if(indexSelected==all) change list all value selected to true
setstate
```

Comment: Can you show how it will look in my code, if not difficult?