# How to select all checkboxes in a Flutter PopupMenu when selecting one checkbox?

Tags: flutter, checkbox, dropdown, popupmenu

A similar question has been asked before for Flutter see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72212542/how-to-select-all-checkboxes-in-dropdownbutton-flutter-when-selecting-one-checkb).  However no valid answer was given, so it may be worth reopening.

Here is a complete code example.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

const cities = <String>{
  'Atlanta',
  'Baltimore',
  'Boston',
  'Chicago',
  'Denver',
  'Houston',
  'Los Angeles',
  'Philadelphia',
  'San Francisco',
  'Washington, DC',
};

enum SelectionState {
  all('(All)'),
  none('(None)'),
  some('(Some)');

  const SelectionState(this._value);
  final String _value;

  @override
  String toString() => _value;
}

class SelectionModel {
  SelectionModel({required this.selection, required this.choices});

  late final Set<String> selection;
  final Set<String> choices;

  SelectionState get selectionState {
    if (selection.isEmpty) return SelectionState.none;
    if (choices.difference(selection).isNotEmpty) {
      return SelectionState.some;
    } else {
      return SelectionState.all;
    }
  }

  SelectionModel add(String value) {
    if (value == '(All)') {
      return SelectionModel(selection: {...choices}, choices: choices);
    } else {
      return SelectionModel(selection: selection..add(value), choices: choices);
    }
  }

  SelectionModel remove(String value) {
    if (value == '(All)') {
      return SelectionModel(selection: <String>{}, choices: choices);
    } else {
      selection.remove(value);
      return SelectionModel(selection: selection, choices: choices);
    }
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dropdown with Select (All)',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  SelectionModel model =
      SelectionModel(selection: {...cities}, choices: {...cities});

  List<PopupMenuItem<String>> getCheckboxList() {
    var out = <PopupMenuItem<String>>[];
    out.add(PopupMenuItem<String>(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        value: '(All)',
        child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            value: model.selectionState == SelectionState.all,
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            title: const Text('(All)'),
            onChanged: (bool? checked) {
              setState(() {
                if (checked!) {
                  model = model.add('(All)');
                } else {
                  model = model.remove('(All)');
                }
              });
            },
          );
        })));

    for (final value in model.choices) {
      out.add(PopupMenuItem<String>(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          value: value,
          child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return CheckboxListTile(
              value: model.selection.contains(value),
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              title: Text(value),
              onChanged: (bool? checked) {
                setState(() {
                  if (checked!) {
                    model = model.add(value);
                  } else {
                    model = model.remove(value);
                  }
                });
              },
            );
          })));
    }
    return out;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 250,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 400),
                  position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(model.selectionState.toString()),
                        const Spacer(),
                        const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context) {
                    return getCheckboxList();
                  },
                  onCanceled: () {
                    setState(() {
                      model = SelectionModel(
                          selection: model.selection, choices: model.choices);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Text('Selected cities: ${model.selection.join(', ')}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

See screeenshot.
[image: base1]

If I click individual cities, everything is fine.  If I click the (All) checkbox, I would like all the checkboxes to turn false (which does not happen unless I close the menu.)

How can I do this?  If I just have a list of CheckboxListTiles in the main app, the logic works fine, and the checkboxes update as I want.  However, once they are part of the menu, it doesn't work properly anymore.

Thank you for any help with this!
Tony

Comment: Are you using setState after you update the state of all of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bridge a connection between `all` and others items. Using separate `StateFulBuilder` is just updating different section of UI. I am extending this approach with ValueNotifier.

```dart
  SelectionModel selectAll() {
    return SelectionModel(selection: {...choices}, choices: choices);
  }

  SelectionModel selectNone() {
    return SelectionModel(selection: <String>{}, choices: choices);
  }
```

And the ValueNotifier.

```dart
  ValueNotifier<SelectionModel> model = ValueNotifier(
      SelectionModel(selection: {...cities}, choices: {...cities}));
```

```dart
///there are N things can be improved, 
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

const cities = <String>{
  'Atlanta',
  'Baltimore',
  'Boston',
  'Chicago',
  'Denver',
  'Houston',
  'Los Angeles',
  'Philadelphia',
  'San Francisco',
  'Washington, DC',
};

enum SelectionState {
  all('(All)'),
  none('(None)'),
  some('(Some)');

  const SelectionState(this._value);
  final String _value;

  @override
  String toString() => _value;
}

class SelectionModel {
  SelectionModel({required this.selection, required this.choices});

  late final Set<String> selection;
  final Set<String> choices;

  SelectionState get selectionState {
    if (selection.isEmpty) return SelectionState.none;
    if (choices.difference(selection).isNotEmpty) {
      return SelectionState.some;
    } else {
      return SelectionState.all;
    }
  }

  SelectionModel add(String value) {
    if (value == '(All)') {
      return SelectionModel(selection: {...choices}, choices: choices);
    } else {
      return SelectionModel(selection: selection..add(value), choices: choices);
    }
  }

  SelectionModel remove(String value) {
    if (value == '(All)') {
      return SelectionModel(selection: <String>{}, choices: choices);
    } else {
      selection.remove(value);
      return SelectionModel(selection: selection, choices: choices);
    }
  }

  SelectionModel selectAll() {
    return SelectionModel(selection: {...choices}, choices: choices);
  }

  SelectionModel selectNone() {
    return SelectionModel(selection: <String>{}, choices: choices);
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dropdown with Select (All)',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ValueNotifier<SelectionModel> model = ValueNotifier(
      SelectionModel(selection: {...cities}, choices: {...cities}));

  List<PopupMenuItem<String>> getCheckboxList(setStateSB) {
    var out = <PopupMenuItem<String>>[];
    out.add(PopupMenuItem<String>(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        value: '(All)',
        child: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: model,
          builder: (context, value, child) => CheckboxListTile(
              value: model.value.selectionState == SelectionState.all,
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              title: const Text('(All)'),
              onChanged: (bool? checked) {
                if (checked == true) {
                  model.value = model.value.selectAll();
                } else {
                  model.value = model.value.selectNone();
                }
                setStateSB(() {});
              }),
        )));

    for (final value in model.value.choices) {
      out.add(PopupMenuItem<String>(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          value: value,
          child: ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: model,
            builder: (context, _, child) => CheckboxListTile(
              // just using your approach
              value: model.value.selection.contains(value),
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              title: Text(value),
              onChanged: (bool? checked) {
                setStateSB(() {
                  if (checked!) {
                    model.value = model.value.add(value);
                  } else {
                    model.value = model.value.remove(value);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          )));
    }
    return out;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 250,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                child: StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (context, setStateSB) => PopupMenuButton<String>(
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 400),
                    position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(model.value.selectionState.toString()),
                          const Spacer(),
                          const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context) {
                      return getCheckboxList(setStateSB);
                    },
                    onCanceled: () {
                      setState(() {
                        model.value = SelectionModel(
                            selection: model.value.selection,
                            choices: model.value.choices);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Text('Selected cities: ${model.value.selection.join(', ')}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yeasin.  I understood what needed to be done but I was not even aware of  `ValueNotifier`, `ValueListenableBuilder` and how they should be used.  I need to learn that!  Your response works as expected.

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html)